# Using SharePoint with Google Apps for Business email

Tags: wss-3.0, email, central-administration, smtp

I am trying to get SharePoint's email features to work with Google Apps (alerts, emails generated by workflows, etc).

Google Apps uses port 587 for smtp and I know that the default smtp port cannot be changed in SharePoint, so I have attempted to set up a new smtp virtual server as an smtp relay. In this, I've enabled TLS, and set the default TCP port to 587.

Under Central Admin -> Operations -> Outgoing Email Settings I already set up the correct configuration - I think:

To test this I'm using a program created by [Rodney Viana](http://rodneyviana.codeplex.com/releases/view/19103). This reports "Email has been sent successfully via SharePoint", but I don't receive it.

- Outbound SMTP server - IP address of my smtp server
- From Address - administrator@foo.com
- Reply-to Address - blank
- Character Set - 65001 (Unicode UTF-8)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This seems kinda "dirty" but it works.

http://www.delphi-ts.com/blogs/lozzi/post/2011/02/09/Sending-SharePoint-emails-through-alternate-ports.aspx

Basically setting up a proxy for sending mail, pointing SharePoint to the proxy (standard port), and allowing the proxy to relay to the correct destination port.

Comment: Yeah when I read this I was thinking a smtp proxy, it's the only real way.

Comment: This is the setup I have already tried (except that my SMTP server is running on a separate physical server). This may or may not be the problem, I can't tell. I will try installing an smtp server on the sharepoint server.

Comment: I also notice that the blogger in your linked article failed to get TLS working. Ideally I would like TLS to be enabled. Thanks for the link anyway - I'll try following it step by step.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and you are right with the TLS issue.

**[HOWEVER enter codeplex proxy solution](http://smtpproxy.codeplex.com/)**

Does what it says "SMTP Proxy for GMail and Windows Live Mail/Hotmail"

Worked perfectly for my email alerts on my test server, while testing it.

Comment: Looks nice. I'll try it.

Comment: I just CANNOT get this to work. I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.91:25" where 192.168.1.91 is my sharepoint server and where SMTPProxy is running.